# Python 3 XML Canonicalization

Tags: python, xml, canonicalization

In Python 3, I need to Canonicalize (c14n) an XML string.

Which module/package can I use for this? And how should I do this?

For reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/

Answer (score 3):

Simplest would probably be:

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring

This function takes `method='c14n'`, `exclusive` and `with-comments` which all are `c14n` canonicalization related.

It is not perfect but would get your 90% there... you would still want to manually check things.

Next a little less pythonic would be libxml2... though in my very limited experience with it is even more tricky.

Comment: You might want `c14n2` these days, mostly for speed reasons.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/